# How to get the MAC address of my ibeacon?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, core-bluetooth, mac-address

I am developing an iOS application in which I need to get my `ibeacon`'s MAC address, so that I can send it to server and recognize that it belongs to which store exactly. I understand that apple hides some of the data for security reasons but in my case I want to get the MAC address of just **my OWN ibeacons**.

Should I use `CoreBluetooth` or `CoreLocation` or both of them together or maybe a `pod`?Is this possible? If it is, how?

Comment: This is what the `uuid`, `major` and `minor` are for.  Why would you think that the MAC address would be any more secure than these values?

Comment: As @Paulw11 say you have to use the major and minor id for detecting the nearby ibeacons.

Comment: So no one else can change the UUID, major and minor values? and what about the "name"? can anyone else change these?

Comment: Different beacon vendors have different configuration techniques but it is typically via a a password or PIN protected protocol.  Additionally many beacons are only configurable for a short period after power-on.  The biggest risk with beacons is someone spoofing your beacon somewhere else, since the UUID, major and minor are broadcast, but so is the MAC address, so that won't help you as it can also be spoofed.  An iBeacon doesn't have a publicly visible name

Comment: ow good , but isn't MAC address unique? i mean can anyone change their own beacon's MAC address for spoofing?

Comment: Yes, MAC addresses can be changed.

Comment: @SaeedHajizade "Peer Address is basically useless - the MAC address of a device can change if privacy is enabled. So every 15 mins or so (depends on settings) a device could change its MAC address.  Nevermind that the MAC address is not necessarily guaranteed to be unique unless you purchased a block of IEEE addresses (almost no vendor does except the chipset vendors)." https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8442